# pause only one AVAudioPlayerNode

Tags: objective-c, audio, avfoundation

I encounter some problems with AVFoundation and sound spatialisation.

I have several instances of player (AVAudioPlayerNode) attached to the audio engine.
they are connected to one environment node (AVAudioEnvironmentNode). the players node play some mini sounds. An finally, the environment node is connected to the main mixer

```
[engine mainMixerNode];
```

It works great, but when I decide to pause one particular player with

```
[player pause];
```

It pause the player but also all the other playerNodes.